# Issue about create .app using py2app with setuptools 2.2

Tags: python

I try to convert my script into app using Py2app, I am using Python3 and Mountain Lion OS.
I downloaded setuptools 2.2 and installed it.

My problem is that whenever I create an app with Alias it works fine.

```
Eg: python3 setup.py py2app -A
```

but if I try to create standalone, it means the .app is not available in the dist folder.

```
Eg: python3 setup.py py2app
```

The last line shows this:

> copying file /Users/kalidoss-pt103/Library/Python/3.2/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools-2.2-py3.2.egg/_markerlib/**init**.pyc  ->  /Users/kalidoss-pt103/Documents/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/python3.2-standalone/app/collect/_markerlib/**init**.pyc
>       error: No such file or directory: /Users/kalidoss-pt103/Library/Python/3.2/lib/python/site-packages/setuptools-2.2-py3.2.egg/_markerlib/**init**.pyc

The app can created and works perfectly works in Python 2.x versions, but not in 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem at the entry point in the setup.py, now it is work fine.